# Uncaught Error in SQL syntax

Tags: php, sql

I don't know what wrong with my code but It looks perfect to me and no problem, but when I tried passing the variables it gives me an error

`Uncaught Error: Syntax Error : Unrecognized Expression`

and that expression is below.

`Select * FROM table_name WHERE first_name = "'.$fname.'" AND last_name = "'.$lname.'";`

The script that Im passing is written below;

```
var url = 'http://localhost/newFolder/get_names.php;
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET',
        cache: "true",
    data:{'first_name':fname,
          'last_name': lname},
    success:function(results){
        $('#result').html(results);
    }
});
```

in the **get_names.php**

```
if(isset($_GET['fist_name'])){

$fname= $_GET['fist_name'];
$lname = $_GET['last_name'];

$query = 'SELECT * FROM `university_list` WHERE
      `first_name` = "' . $fname. '" AND
          `last_name` = "' . $lname. '"';
//code continue............
```

Comment: Print out `$query` and post what it looks like.

Comment: `fist_name` ? are you sure about this?

Comment: it was a jquery problem, thanx. I have solved it.

Comment: You're also passing JSON data on your GET request, so `$_GET['first_name']` probably isn't what you expect.